# How to Create a Global High Score With Phaser?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, phaser-framework

I've been using the [phaser](http://phaser.io/) JavaScript framework for making games that can be put into HTML and I can't seem to figure out how to make a high score system.

I've only been able to find solutions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37408825/create-a-high-score-in-phaser) but it seems to store the high score value locally on the client's system so they can only see their own high score. I would like to be able to have a global high score with highest levels and names if possible.

I understand that most likely I will have to make a SQL database to store all of this and move it between the game and database with node.js (I have very limited knowledge of both SQL and node.js) but I don't know specifically how that is supposed to tie in with Phaser. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know SQL (and you're not going to be holding that much data anyways), you can probably make do with a JSON file. This answer assumes you have a server (you need one if you're planning to use Node.js). Also, I'm assumming you want to make an [old-school high score table](http://photos.1highscore.com/score11100_20140703114726.jpg), with a score and a name.

This intends to be a general guidance. You will need to find how to do what I'm explaining in your language of choice.

**In your server** you will have a file (e.g. scores.json), that will look like the following:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "Destroyer",
            "score": 23
        },
        {
            "name": "yo momma",
            "score": 5
        },
        {
            "name": "Joe",
            "score": 1
        },
        // And so on...
    ]
}
```

Also in your server, you will need to have something listening on a specific port (you can use Node.js, PHP, Ruby, Python, etc.), which is where you will make your requests. What this script will do is (in JavaScript):

```
handleRequest(request) {

    // Fetch your file and populate the array
    var scoresTable = ...

    // On request, decide which type of request it is
    if (request.type === "getHighScoresTable") {

        // If it wants the scores, return the json as a string
        return scoresJson;

    } else if (request.type === "submitScore"
            && request.score > scoresTable[scoresTable.length - 1].score) {

        // Otherwise, check if the submitted score makes it into the table. 
        // If it does, search its position and replace.
        scoresTable.forEach(function(value, index) {
            if (value.score < request.score) {
                scoresTable.splice(index, 0, {"name": request.name, "score": request.score});
            }
        });

        // Trim the last element and return
         scoresTable = scoresTable.slice(0, -1)

        // You probably want to update your file here
    }

}
```

Now, **on your JavaScript client-side file**, you should make an [AJAX request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) to your server when you want to save a new score or get the high scores table. jQuery offers a [nicer syntax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'urlToYourServer',
        type: 'GET',
        data: '{
            "type": "submitScore",
            "name": "I beat Joe",
            "score": 2
        }'
    });
```

It's probably a good idea to check if the score is high enough in the client before you send it. Also, you might want to consider some security measures, since any user will be able to cheat doing a request from their client.